# How to convert raw packet data into a PCAP file?

Tags: pcap, libpcap, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I'm running some software that sniffs local packets, then encapsulates the full, raw packet data in a TCP packet and sends it to the server.

What I'd like to do is have the server receive the packet data and put it into a PCAP file for download by anyone who is connected to the server.

Basically what I need is some inspired information regarding the PCAP file format and how to make entries into a PCAP file using raw packet data without using a packet sniffer.

Can this be done and if so how?

Comment: What language do you want to use? There are pcap libraries in most languages.

Comment: *"... inspired information regarding the PCAP file format ..."* - there is enough information out there about the file format, like https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat. The format is actually pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to tell without looking at your data and knowing what tool you are using to capture the packet.

It might be as simple as adding a global header.

> The global header contains the magic number, GMT offset, timestamp
>   precision, the maximum length of captured packets (in octets), and the
>   data link type. This information is followed by zero or more records
>   of captured packet data.

If you are using `tcpdump` then the output might already be pcap compatible. If not, just install `tcpdump-libpcap` and then use that version.

EXAMPLE PCAP STRUCTURE:

[image]

SOURCE: https://www.lesliesikos.com/pcap/

For some example code with PCAP headers, check out this Python program:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/612847/Generate-a-quick-and-easy-custom-pcap-file-using-P